# Set an environment variable for embeded wildfly from arquillian test

Tags: java, automated-tests, jboss-arquillian

We use Arquillian with embedded Wildfly to run automated tests for a Java backend application. The Java application uses some environment variables.
Can I bring my arquillian test to set up specific environment variables for the launched wildfly process to influence them by the tests?

Answer (score 1):

When you run an Arqullian test at embedded container through Maven you can specify environment variables at a maven plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkMode>always</forkMode>
        <argLine>-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000</argLine>  
      <redirectTestOutputToFile>false</redirectTestOutputToFile>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

OR at arqullian.xml. But this configuration is limited with an embedded container. Message from running tests:

```
Supported property names: [managementAddress, modulePath, password, bundlePath, managementPort, jbossHome, managementProtocol, cleanServerBaseDir, username]
```

Comment: I am looking for a System Environment Variable, not a Java Environment Property!